# Javascript - How to override css property when appending data?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am appending data to a `top-collection` has id's that I will be appending data to.

The 4th id is currently has a `display:none` property because I am not going to be using the 4th one at all times. When the 4 `id=fourTitle` is needed I will like to change the css property from `display:none` to `display:inblock`.

here is my html :

```
<ul class="top-collection">
 <li class="top-collection-item"><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"><span class="data-circle">1</span><h4 class="top-table-text" id="oneTitle"></h4></div></li>
 <li class="top-collection-item"><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"><span class="data-circle">2</span><h4 class="top-table-text" id="twoTitle"></h4></div></li>
 <li class="top-collection-item"><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"><span class="data-circle">3</span><h4 class="top-table-text" id="threeTitle"></h4></div></li>
<li class="top-collection-item-four"><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"><span class="data-circle">3</span><h4 class="top-table-text" id="fourTitle"></h4></div></li>
  </ul>
```

Here is my append code :

```
  $('#oneTitle').html(topArr[0].sector)
        $('#rankOne').html(topArr[0].result)
        $('#twoTitle').html(topArr[2].sector)
        $('#rankTwo').html( topArr[2].result)
        $('#threeTitle').html(topArr[1].sector)
        $('#rankThree').html(topArr[1].result)
        $('#fourTitle').html(topArr[3].result) // this is where I would like to add display:in block (currently has display:none)
```

I am expecting the `fourTitle` to display when needed it. It is default to `display:none` at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able solve this is issue by using `document.getElementById("#id").style.display = "inline-block"` which changes the styling of the id I targeted.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the jQuery toggle function and simply pass it true/false.

This daisy chain, will toggle the div if `topArr[3].result` has a value and it will set the HTML to that value.

`$('#fourTitle').toggle((topArr[3].result != "")).html(topArr[3].result);`

You can also use jQuery's toggle class, pass the first function the class and the second boolean to determine if you want to add the class or remove it.

`$('#fourTitle').toggleClass("item-four",(topArr[3].result == "")).html(topArr[3].result);`

Comment: Ive impleted this in my code but It does not appear because my div on the html side has class item-four which has `display:none`. Do I need to remove this property before? Im not entirely sure how the code you posted works

Comment: @stepheniok I have updated the answer with an alternative solution, `toggleClass`. If that doesn't work as expected, change `topArr[3].result == ""` to `topArr[3].result != ""`.

Comment: the html still does not show on my page. If I inspect element I can see the data being shown but the display-none property is hiding it